# Laravel Validator always fails

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a simple Validator on a email field. Via JQuery I run the Laravel controller to check the input. But it always fails..

I left the else empty, just to make it more clear.

I also get this error. Find some stackoverflow topics about it and tried the solutions like you see in the code, but that didn't help.

```
422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

My controller function:

```
public function send_mail(Request $request, VendorProfile $profile_id){
        $profile= $profile_id;

        $email = $request->input('contact_e_mail');
        $contact_first_name = $request->input('contact_first_name');
        $email_profile = $profile->email;
        $name_profile = $profile->name;

        $rules = [
            'contact_e_mail' => 'required|email',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            if($request->ajax())
            {
                return response()->json(array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'There are incorect values in the form!',
                    'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray(),
                ), 422);
            }

            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        } else {
        }
    }
```

my view:

```
<div class="events single-event">
    <div class="o-grid">
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                <h4>@lang('profile.contactTitle')</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                {!! Form::label('', __('profile.contactSalutation').'*') !!}
                @if( Session::get('urlLang') == "en" )
                    {!! Form::select(__('contact_contactSalutation'), array('Miss' => 'Miss', 'Sir' => 'Sir'),array('class' => 'c-dropdown c-dropdown__simple u-mb-x6'),['required' => 'required']) !!}
                @else
                    {!! Form::select(__('contact_contactSalutation'), array('Frau' => 'Frau', 'Herr' => 'Herr'),array('class' => 'c-dropdown c-dropdown__simple u-mb-x6'),['required' => 'required']) !!}
                @endif
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                <p style="color: #696978; font-size: 14px; text-align: right">@lang('profile.mandatoryField')</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="o-grid">
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                {!! Form::label('contact_first_name', __('profile.contactFirstName').'*') !!}
                {!! Form::text('contact_first_name', null, ['placeholder' => __('profile.contactFirstName'),'class' => 'c-input required','id' => 'contact_first_name','required']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                {!! Form::label('contact_e_mail', __('profile.contactEmail').'*') !!}
                {!! Form::text('contact_e_mail', null, ['placeholder' => __('profile.contactEmail'),'class' => 'c-input required email','id' => 'contact_e_mail','required']) !!}
                <input type="hidden" id="profile_id" value="{{ $profile->id }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                {!! Form::label('contact_last_name', __('profile.contactLastName').'*') !!}
                {!! Form::text('contact_last_name', null, ['placeholder' => __('profile.contactLastName'),'class' => 'c-input required','id' => 'contact_last_name','required']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
                {!! Form::label('contact_phone', __('profile.contactPhone')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('contact_phone', null, ['placeholder' => __('profile.contactPhone'),'class' => 'c-input','id' => 'contact_phone']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12">
            <div class="o-grid__col">
                {!! Form::label('text', __('profile.contactMessageInfo')) !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('contact_text',null,['class' => 'c-input c-input__text required','placeholder' => __('profile.contactMessageInfo'),'id' => 'contact_text','required']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        {{--<div class="o-grid__col u-12/12">
                <label for="captcha">@lang('mail.contactCaptcha')*</label>
        </div>
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <input id="captcha" class="c-input" type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="@lang('mail.contactCaptchaInsert')" required>
        </div>
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <p id="captcha-image-frame">{!! captcha_img('ah_contact') !!}</p>
        </div>--}}
        <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12">
            <input class="c-input__checkbox required" id="toc" type="checkbox" name="agree_to_toc" value="1" required>
            <label class="c-input__checkboxLabel p2" for="toc">
                {!! @trans('global.formTacInfo', [
                    'class' => 'c-link c-link__primary',
                    'link_datenschutz' => route('static.show', ['folder_id' => 28, 'slug' => "datenschutz"])
                    ]) !!}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
            <span class="c-form--haserror" id="alert_message" style="display: none"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="o-grid__col u-text-right">
            <button id="submit_contact_form" class="c-btn c-btn--small c-btn--red" type="submit" style="display: none" onclick="submitForm()">
                <span>@lang('profile.contactSendMessage')</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('#toc').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#submit_contact_form').show();
        }
        else{
            $('#submit_contact_form').hide();
        }
    })

    function submitForm() {
    var profile_id = $("#profile_id").val();
    var contact_e_mail = $("#contact_e_mail").val();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '{{route("profile.sendmail")}}',
        data: {profile_id: profile_id,contact_e_mail:contact_e_mail},
        success: function(data){
            $('#alert_message').hide()
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, json, errorThrown){// this are default for ajax errors
            var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON;
            var errorsHtml = '';
            $.each(errors['errors'], function (index, value) {
                errorsHtml += value;
            });
            $('#alert_message').text(errorsHtml);
            $('#alert_message').show();
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to submit this form via ajax? Because it seems like you are expecting to with that `onclick` event. Your `submitForm()` javascript function does not pass the email in the `data` array: `data: {profile_id: profile_id},`

Comment: Yes I'm submitting via Ajax

Comment: @NMahurin passed the data, still get same error..

Comment: changed the code in original question

Comment: You can add a `dd($request->all())` to the start of your `send_mail()` to see what is being sent via the request. It should show you why the validation is not going through.

Comment: array:2 [▼
  "profile_id" => "1498"
  "contact_e_mail" => "fjdkn@g.com"
]